# Django Ajax communication, Django doesn't recognize as being Ajax (using request.is_ajax() )

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm using Ajax with Django. The data is transmitted further but is not recognize as being Ajax. Browser Chrome/Firefox;

To check if the request is done trough ajax, I use:

```
`request.is_ajax()` method, but this fails, not true, so I checked this method how is working and:

def is_ajax(self):
    return self.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

I verified  `META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH')` and I get `None`;

I'm think is something with ContentType or I need to set another header. But How ?. My JavaScript is set this way :

```
xhr.open('post', event.target.action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.send(data));
```

At a further check seems request.Meta doesn't contain Content-type also.

Comment: Are you including the CRSF method in your post?

Comment: the csrf-token is passed, there are no errors, the only thing is that in Meta there are no headers; are you referring to something else besides the token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

> With the exception of CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE, as given above, any HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name. So, for example, a header called X-Bender would be mapped to the META key HTTP_X_BENDER.

So the name of the header should be `X-Requested-With`:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```